# Deleting pointers in an unorderd map

Tags: c++, artificial-intelligence

I am in AI trying to clean memory in an unoredered map i used for an A* search and the code below is what i am doing for one of my maps. I can't get it working, I need some help.

```
    for (std::unordered_map<Tile*, PlannerNode*>::iterator itr = plan_map.begin(); itr != plan_map.end(); ++itr)
    {
        delete itr;
        itr->second = nullptr;
    }
```

Comment: That's not how unordered maps work. To remove an entry in an unordered map, use its `erase()` method. Note that after you erase an entry in the unordered map, the iterator that was erased becomes invalid, and any operation on it, including trying to increment it in the loop, is undefined behavior, and a guaranteed crash. Open your C++ book to the chapter that explains how maps, and other containers work, and reread it.

Comment: Don't you want to `delete` the same thing you set to `nullptr`?

Comment: the iterator and that is what a friend explained to me how to do it but it dose not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have an `unordered_map` of pointers you need to free the space which they point to, i.e. call `delete` on them.  Afterwards you want to [erase](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map/erase) them from the map rather than setting them to `nullptr`.  The example below might help you.  It will print

```
Destroying Tile
Destroying PlannerNode
```

on your screen.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

struct Tile {
    ~Tile() { std::cout << "Destroying Tile\n"; }
};

struct PlannerNode {
    ~PlannerNode() { std::cout << "Destroying PlannerNode\n"; }
};

int main()
{
    std::unordered_map<Tile*, PlannerNode*> plan_map;
    plan_map.emplace(new Tile, new PlannerNode);
    for (auto itr = plan_map.begin(); itr != plan_map.end(); /* no increment here! */)
    {
        delete itr->first;
        delete itr->second;
        itr = plan_map.erase(itr);
    }
}
```

It would probably be better to use RAII constructs to manage the pointers, e.g. `std::unique_ptr`.  That way you can just let `plan_map` go out of scope and all memory is cleaned up automatically for you.

```
std::unordered_map<std::unique_ptr<Tile>, std::unique_ptr<PlannerNode>> plan_map;
plan_map.emplace(std::make_unique<Tile>(), std::make_unique<PlannerNode>());
```

Comment: nitpicking, but do not erase each time. This will trigger rehash at some point when we are below threshhold. That is suboptimal, considering that we are going to drop all the elements. A better solution is to move to map.clear().

Answer (score 0):

```
std::for_each(plan_map.begin(), plan_map.end(), [](auto& p){delete p.first; delete p.second;});
plan_map.clear();
```

This is a much cleaner way to do it and it also avoids clumsy iterator aritematic.
Understanding lambda syntax is not in scope of the question, I do recommend looking up C++ lambda's to understand this.

do look into `std::unique_ptr<>`, that will help you and all you would need to do would be,
`plan_map.clear()`;

reference:http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each